# Split .srt file into equal chunks

Tags: java, split, srt

I am new to this and i need to split Srt(subtitle file) into multiple chunks.

For example: if i have subtitle file of a video(60 minutes). Then the subtitle file should split into 6 subtitle files having each subtitle file of 10 minutes.

i.e 6 X 10 = 60 Minutes

Need to divide into 6 chunks irrespective of minutes.

Using these each subtitle time/duration, i have to split the video into same chunks.

I am trying this code, can u please help me out how can i calculate the time and divide into chunks,

I am able to achieve how many minutes of chuck i needed.But stuck in how to read upto that chunck minutes from source file and create a new file .Then how to start the next chunk from the next 10 minutes from the source file.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

/**
 * The class SyncSRTSubtitles reads a subtitles .SRT file and offsets all the
 * timestamps with the same specific value in msec.
 *
 * The format of the .SRT file is like this:
 *
 * 123
 * 00:11:23,456 --> 00:11:25,234
 * subtitle #123 text here
 *
 *
 * @author Sorinel CRISTESCU
 */
public class SyncSRTSubtitles {

    /**
     * Entry point in the program.
     *
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        /* INPUT: offset value: negative = less (-) ... positive = more (+). */
        long delta = (22 * 1000L + 000); /* msec */


        /* INPUT: source & destination files */
        String srcFileNm = "/Users/meh/Desktop/avatar.srt";
        String destFileNm = "/Users/meh/Desktop/avatar1.srt";


        /* offset algorithm: START */
        File outFile = new File(destFileNm);
        outFile.createNewFile();
        FileWriter ofstream = new FileWriter(outFile);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(ofstream);

        /* Open the file that is the first command line parameter */
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(srcFileNm);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
//        List<String> doc = IOUtils.readLines(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);


String strEnd = null;
        long diff = 0;
        String line;
        String startTS1;
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(srcFileNm))) {
            line = lines.skip(1).findFirst().get();
            String[] atoms = line.split(" --> ");
             startTS1 = atoms[0];

        }
        System.out.println("bolo:" +line);
        System.out.println("startTS1:" +startTS1);

        String startTS = null;
        String endTS = null;
        /* Read File Line By Line */
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] atoms = strLine.split(" --> ");
            if (atoms.length == 1) {
                //out.write(strLine + "\n");
            }
            else {
                 startTS = atoms[0];


                 endTS = atoms[1];
//                out.write(offsetTime(startTS, delta) + " --> "
//                    + offsetTime(endTS, delta) + "\n");
                strEnd = endTS;

            }


        }
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
            Date parsedendDate = dateFormat.parse(strEnd);
            Date parsedStartDate = dateFormat.parse(startTS1);
            diff = parsedendDate.getTime() - parsedStartDate.getTime();

        } catch(Exception e) { //this generic but you can control another types of exception
            // look the origin of excption
        }
        System.out.println("strEnd");
        System.out.println(strEnd);
        /* Close the input streams */
        in.close();
        out.close();
        System.out.println(diff);
        long diff1 =diff/6;
        System.out.println(diff1);
        long diff2= (diff1*6);
        System.out.println(diff2);
        System.out.println((diff / 3600000) + " hour/s " + (diff % 3600000) / 60000 + " minutes");
        System.out.println((diff1 / 3600000) + " hour/s " + (diff1 % 3600000) / 60000 + " minutes");
        System.out.println((diff2 / 3600000) + " hour/s " + (diff2 % 3600000) / 60000 + " minutes");

        /* offset algorithm: END */
        System.out.println("DONE! Check the rsult oin the file: " + destFileNm);
    }

    /**
     * Computes the timestamp offset.
     *
     * @param ts
     *            String value of the timestamp in format: "hh:MM:ss,mmm"
     * @param delta
     *            long value of the offset in msec (positive or negative).
     * @return String with the new timestamp representation.
     */
    private static String offsetTime(String ts, long delta) {
        long tsMsec = 0;
        String atoms[] = ts.split("\\,");
        if (atoms.length == 2) {
            tsMsec += Integer.parseInt(atoms[1]);
        }
        atoms = atoms[0].split(":");

        tsMsec += Integer.parseInt(atoms[2]) * 1000L; /* seconds */
        tsMsec += Integer.parseInt(atoms[1]) * 60000L; /* minutes */
        tsMsec += Integer.parseInt(atoms[0]) * 3600000L; /* hours */
        tsMsec += delta; /* here we do the offset. */

        long h = tsMsec / 3600000L;
        System.out.println(h);

        String result = get2digit(h, 2) + ":";

        System.out.println(result);


        long r = tsMsec % 3600000L;
        System.out.println(r);

        long m = r / 60000L;
        System.out.println(m);

        result += get2digit(m, 2) + ":";
        System.out.println(result);
        r = r % 60000L;
        System.out.println(r);

        long s = r / 1000L;
        result += get2digit(s, 2) + ",";

        result += get2digit(r % 1000L, 3);
        System.out.println(result);

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the string representation of the number, adding the prefix '0' to
     * have the required length.
     *
     * @param n
     *            long number to convert to string.
     * @param digits
     *            int number of digits required.
     * @return String with the required length string (3 for digits = 3 -->
     *         "003")
     */
    private static String get2digit(long n, int digits) {
        String result = "" + n;
        while (result.length() < digits) {
            result = "0" + result;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Please suggest me how can i achieve this?

Comment: do you always need it in chunks of 10 minutes or how exactly should the chunks be?

Comment: i need to be splitted into equal chunks... if its 10 minutes, then if i want 5 chunks, then it should split by 2 minutes each.. if i have file of 120 minutes files. if i need 6 chunks, 20 min of each file... such kind of output i need @XtremeBaumer

Comment: You need a consistent way to know how many chunks you need. How many chunks would you need for 65/79/88 mins?

Comment: it may vary movie by movie. Ok will fix to 6 chunks for irrespective of minutes. And all 6 should be written in 6 .srt files

Comment: @XtremeBaumer need 6 chunks irrespective of minutes. and it should be written in 6 different .srt files. How can i achieve this? please suggest

Comment: If you don't know the length of the video in before, then you need to get the last timestamp from the file. Once you know the length you calculate the size of the chunks. With this  size you can read the file and check when you need to start a new file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174263/discussion-between-user6250770-and-xtremebaumer).

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Use an [existing library](https://github.com/jonathanedgecombe/srt-library).

Comment: @rustyx in the provided code everything is fine, just i need to calculate the time and divide into chunks.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer updated my code here. apologies for the repost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a way to divide the file into chunks,

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
String FilePath = "/Users/meh/Desktop/escapeplan.srt";
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(FilePath);

        System.out.println("size: " +fin.getChannel().size());
        long abc = 0l;
        abc = (fin.getChannel().size())/3;
        System.out.println("6: " +abc);
System.out.println("abc: " +abc);
       //FilePath = args[1];
        File filename = new File(FilePath);
        long splitFileSize = 0,bytefileSize=0;
        if (filename.exists()) {
            try {
                //bytefileSize = Long.parseLong(args[2]);
                splitFileSize = abc;
                Splitme spObj = new Splitme();
                spObj.split(FilePath, (long) splitFileSize);
                spObj = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("File Not Found....");
        }
}
    public void split(String FilePath, long splitlen) {

            long leninfile = 0, leng = 0;
            int count = 1, data;
            try {
                File filename = new File(FilePath);
                InputStream infile = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
                data = infile.read();
                System.out.println("data");
                System.out.println(data);

                while (data != -1) {
                    filename = new File("/Users/meh/Documents/srt" + count + ".srt");
    //RandomAccessFile outfile = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");

                    OutputStream outfile = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
                    while (data != -1 && leng < splitlen) {
                        outfile.write(data);
                        leng++;
                        data = infile.read();
                    }
                    leninfile += leng;
                    leng = 0;
                    outfile.close();
                    changeTimeStamp(filename, count);

                    count++;


                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to parse the file twice:

- once to read the last end time
- second time to process all lines and
  generate output files.

```
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

    public class SplitSRTFiles {

        /**
         * Splits a SRT file in multiple files each containing an equal time duration.
         * @param args
         * [0] number of wanted chunks
         * [1] source file name
         * @throws IOException
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            int nrOfChunks = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            File srtFile = new File(args[1]);
            System.out.println("Splitting "+srtFile.getAbsolutePath()+" into "+nrOfChunks+" files.");

            List<String> srcLines = FileUtils.readLines(srtFile);
            long fileEndTime = lastEndTime(srcLines);
            long msecsPerChunkFile = fileEndTime / nrOfChunks;
            int destFileCounter = 1;
            String[] fileNameParts = srtFile.getName().split("\\.");
            File outFile = new File(fileNameParts[0] + destFileCounter + "." + fileNameParts[1]);
            System.out.println("Writing to "+outFile.getAbsolutePath());
            outFile.createNewFile();
            FileWriter ofstream = new FileWriter(outFile);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(ofstream);

            for (String line : srcLines) {
                String[] atoms = line.split(" --> ");
                if (atoms.length > 1) {
                    long startTS = toMSec(atoms[0]);
                    // check if start time of this subtitle is after the current
                    // chunk
                    if (startTS > msecsPerChunkFile * destFileCounter) {
                        // close existing file ...
                        out.close();
                        ofstream.close();
                        // ... and start a new file
                        destFileCounter++;
                        outFile = new File(srtFile.getParent(), fileNameParts[0] + destFileCounter + "." + fileNameParts[1]);
                        System.out.println("Writing to "+outFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        outFile.createNewFile();
                        ofstream = new FileWriter(outFile);
                        out = new BufferedWriter(ofstream);
                    }
                }
                out.write(line + "/n");
            }
            out.close();
            ofstream.close();
            System.out.println("Done.");
        }

        /**
         * Calculates the time in msec of the end time of the last subtitle of the
         * file
         * 
         * @param lines
         *            read from file
         * @return end time in milliseconds of the last subtitle
         */
        public static long lastEndTime(List lines) throws IOException {
            String endTS = null;
            for (String line : lines) {
                String[] atoms = line.split(" --> ");
                if (atoms.length > 1) {
                    endTS = atoms[1];
                }
            }
            return endTS == null ? 0L : toMSec(endTS);
        }

        public static long toMSec(String time) {
            long tsMsec = 0;
            String atoms[] = time.split("\\,");
            if (atoms.length == 2) {
                tsMsec += Integer.parseInt(atoms[1]);
            }
            atoms = atoms[0].split(":");

            tsMsec += Integer.parseInt(atoms[2]) * 1000L; /* seconds */
            tsMsec += Integer.parseInt(atoms[1]) * 60000L; /* minutes */
            tsMsec += Integer.parseInt(atoms[0]) * 3600000L; /* hours */
            return tsMsec;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But i'm getting error on "for(String line: )" incompatible types. expected object but found String.